# PHP explode string by html tag

Tags: php, string

Suppose string $a holds

```
<p>Phasellus blandit enim eget odio euismod eu dictum quam scelerisque.
</p><p>Sed ut diam nisi.</p><p>Ut vestibulum volutpat luctus.</p>
```

How can I explode this into this array

```
Array(
    [0] = '<p>Phasellus blandit enim eget odio euismod eu dictum quam scelerisque.</p>';
    [1] = '<p>Sed ut diam nisi. Ut vestibulum volutpat luctus.</p>';
    [2] = '<p>Ut vestibulum volutpat luctus.</p>';
)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using DOMDocument and DOMXPath (a bit overkill if only a simple solution is needed):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($a);
$domx = new DOMXPath($dom);
$entries = $domx->evaluate("//p");
$arr = array();
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    $arr[] = '<' . $entry->tagName . '>' . $entry->nodeValue .  '</' . $entry->tagName . '>';
}
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: You may consider calling `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` first to avoid DOMDocument polluting your standard error handler with HTML related errors. Implement your own handler to catch the errors instead. See the comments in http://php.net/manual/de/domdocument.loadhtml.php for more information.

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php
$ps    = array();
$count = preg_match_all('/<p[^>]*>(.*?)<\/p>/is', $a, $matches);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
    $ps[] = $matches[0][$i];
}
```

That could be one way.  Or you could use a loop with [strpos](http://php.net/strpos)

Comment: preg is faster for basic parsing like this.

Comment: we are speaking about php and its slow. anyway, you can save a couple of miliseconds on it but loose a couple of hours thying to make this code working with more complex strings.

Comment: Nice demo ~ but this is `not` the correct way ~ parsing html with RegEx is a recipe for disaster...