# Get all strings between two delimiters (sub strings) with regex PHP

Tags: php, regex

Can anybody help me with a function in php using regex to return all founded sub strings between two delimiters.

expmple :

```
<p class="mn"><a href="123517/2882"> Hi all 5 </a>
<p class="mn"><a href="123518/2662"> Hi all 6 </a>
<p class="mn"><a href="123519/2552"> Hi all 55 </a>
<p class="mn"><a href="1235100/7722"> Hi all 15</a>
```

I need to get all substrings between `<p class="mn"><a href="` and `">` using **regex php** function.

***I tried some methods here but I can not handle regex syntax rightly, so I need a help with regex syntax and how to use it.***

thanks

Comment: `I tried some methods` what methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the specific sense, try

```
preg_match_all('@<p class="mn"><a href="(.+?)">@', $str, $m);
```

In the general sense, [parse the HTML with a library and use XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509774/php-explode-string-by-html-tag/7509850#7509850).